unhandledRejection: TypeError: file.arrayBuffer is not a function in NextJs
I am using formidable-serverless in nextJs to handle file upload. I need to convert the uploaded file to bufferedImage in order to upload it in AWS S3. But when I am trying to convert the parse file  arrayBuffer() function it is not working giving error unhandledRejection: TypeError: file.arrayBuffer is not a function.
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
     //console.log(err, fields, files);

     const file = files.file;
     console.log("File",file);

     const bufferedImage = await file.arrayBuffer();

